# criteriaBuilder selectCase in aggregate function throw QuerySyntaxException

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I want to do a select case in a aggregate function but it throw a `QuerySyntaxException` :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: case near line 1, column 125 : [select new com.dev.entity.User(generatedAlias0.id, generatedAlias0.name, generatedAlias0.date, generatedAlias0.mode, count(case when generatedAlias0.id=:param2 then :param3 else :param4 end)) from com.renault.dev.User as generatedAlias0]
```

like if the `case` function is not recognized :/

There is the criteria query

```
Expression<String> idCountCase = builder.<String>selectCase().when(builder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.id), "id01"), "EXISTS").otherwise("NOT EXISTS");
Expression<Long> idCount = builder.count(idCountCase);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(userRoot.get(User_.id), userRoot.get(User_.name), userRoot.get(User_.date), userRoot.get(User_.mode), idCount);
```

Any advices please ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I just updated Hibernate version and it works now . I guess condition in aggregate function was not supported in previous version...